# Butterknife's unbinder + Conductor's Controller

Tags: butterknife, conductor

I use `Butterknife` for binding views inside `Conductor`'s controllers. Should I unbind these views inside a `Controller`'s `onDestroyView()`, as [recommended](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) for Android Fragments?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's how they do it in their [sample](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/Conductor/blob/df70e983be2f4b37930b78bf8fee90e77b57e53c/demo/src/main/java/com/bluelinelabs/conductor/demo/controllers/base/ButterKnifeController.java#L37).

```
@Override
protected void onDestroyView(@NonNull View view) {
    super.onDestroyView(view);
    unbinder.unbind();
    unbinder = null;
}
```